# PHPBrowser Hidden API method "_loadPage" is not following 301 Redirects

Tags: redirect, codeception

I am writing a test with PHPBowser, in Codeception v2.2.11 that uses the hidden API method of [_loadpage](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser#_loadPage).

I have added this into my \Helper\Api as follows:

```
public function loadpage($link)
    {
        $this->getModule('PhpBrowser')->_loadPage('POST', $link);

    }
```

And call it in an Api Codeception test, as follows:

```
$link = 'http://www.fiercebiotech.com/contact';
$I->loadpage($link);
```

The issue I am facing is that when using `_loadpage`, it does not follow redirects. This exampled link when finally resolved is 301 redirected to:
http://www.fiercebiotech.com/contact-us.

Here is the header response console output when `_loadpage` opens `$link`.

```
   I loadpage "http://www.fiercebiotech.com/contact"
  [Request Headers] []
  [Page] http://www.fiercebiotech.com/contact
  [Response] 404
```

I need help getting `_loadpage` to not stop at ~/contact but follow the 301 redirect to  ~/contact-us, so I can get the output header response to be

```
[page] http://www.fiercebiotech.com/contact-us
[response] 200
```

Currently I cant get `_loadpage` to follow 301 redirects. Anyone out there have success doing so?

Ive attempted to use Codeception REST function startFollowingRedirects and adding `allow_redirects: true` as follows, but neither technique seems to work (as the redirect is not followed).

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: ''
            browser: 'chrome'
            window_size: 1200x993
            clear_cookies: true
            allow_redirects: true
        - \Helper\Acceptance
        - REST:
            url: 'host'
            depends: PhpBrowser
            allow_redirects: true
        - \Helper\Api
```

Comment: Your problem is that you get 404 status, not 301.

Comment: Thank you @Naktibalda for your response.

The issue is if I visit the link ~/contact (as it is in the source code) in Chrome, the links resolves to a 301 when it gets to it final destination at ~/contact-us. 
As seen in this video grab - https://www.screencast.com/t/B0qs8c8v

Here is the header response I get from Chrome:
`Status Code URL IP Page Type Redirect Type Redirect URL 
301 http://www.fiercebiotech.com/contact 54.225.158.254 server_redirect permanent http://www.fiercebiotech.com/contact-us
200 http://www.fiercebiotech.com/contact-us 54.225.158.254 normal none none`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my issue:

The issue began with, as I suspected is that `_loadpage` does not follow redirects, it only loads the page requested and stops. In this case '~/contact-us', ignoring the fact that the page gets redirected to (with a `301`) to '~/contact-us'.

I cant simply load the page (via `_loadpage`)
Get the header response
and assume that I will be getting the header response of the redirected URL
I will only get the header response of the original URL.

**The Solution:**
I have to in my `foreach` loop:

1. Go to the URL
2. send a `GET`
3. Grab the HTTP Header
4. Assert that the HTTP header has a `200OK` response

Solution - As it is in Codeception code:

```
public function Validate_httpStatus_mainNav($mainNavLocator)
{
    //Used to test main navigation -- 404 tests
    $I = $this;
    $mainNavLinks = $I->grabMultiple($mainNavLocator, 'href');
    codecept_debug($mainNavLinks);
    foreach ($mainNavLinks as $link) {
        $I->amOnUrl($link);
        $I->sendGET($link);
        $I->grabHttpHeader($link);
        $I->canSeeResponseCodeIs(HttpCode::OK);
    }
}
```